# Тип предложений

Tags: синтаксис

Научите меня, пожалуйста, определить тип предложений выделенных фрагментов.

> 1) Она посмотрела на пьяную подругу и ужаснулась: **как бы она сейчас и
>   на самом деле не сняла платье.**
>
> 2) Прошу только одного – **поговори с братом!**
>
> 3) Она хотела только одного – **пусть он вернется.**

(я руководствуюсь(?) перифразами tipo *"она ужаснулась, как бы она не сняла платье" / "прошу тебя о том, чтобы ты поговорил с братом" / "хотела, чтобы он вернулся"* и прихожу к изъяснительным предложениям 
(но наверняка не правильно делаю... + императивные конструкции в (2) и (3) меня вводят в заблуждение)

> 4) Прошу только об одном – **разрешить мне видеться с малышом.**
>
> 5) Мне от тебя нужно только одно – **снять с тебя мерки.**

(здесь тоже пыталась через перифразу tipo *"прошу тебя, чтобы ты разрешила ....."*, но наве́рное нельзя считать то, что стоит после тире как отдельное предложение, да?)

> 6) Он был против: **как так – под его крышей будут говорить о М.**

(через контекст я поняла, что *"как так"* выражает негодование и причину, почему персонаж против, но с синтаксической точки зрения мои знания = нуль)

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

1) Она посмотрела на пьяную подругу и ужаснулась: как бы она сейчас и на самом деле не сняла платье.- бессоюзное сложное предложение, где вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой ( ужаснулась чему? в чём именно ужас?в возможности  снять платье на самом деле)

2) Прошу только одного – поговори с братом!- то же самое, бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой,но вместо двоеточия стоит тире, современный синтаксис в художественной литературе это допускает как разговорную конструкцию (в учебной литературе нет).

Тире допускается, если вторая часть имеет изъяснительное значение: Прошу только одного (чего именно? о чём прошу?) - (это) поговори с братом. Синонимично сложноподчинённому предложению с  придаточным изъяснительным:Прошу только о том, чтобы ты поговорил  с братом.

3) Она хотела только одного – пусть он вернется.- то же самое: тире вместо двоеточия, вторая часть имеет изъяснительное значение и синонимично конструкции Она хотела только одного - (это) чтоб он вернулся. Тоже экспрессивная разговорная конструкция.

4 и 5 конструкции точно такие же по смыслу, но  это простые предложения, они отличаются от БСП тем,что местоимённое слово ОДНО разъясняется не предложением, а пояснительным членом предложения, именно поэтому там тире.

6) Он был против(почему?): как так – под его крышей будут говорить о М. С двоеточием понятно: бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть указывает на причину того, о чём говорится в первой. "Как так" - действительно выражение негодования, после него идёт пояснение, что вызвало негодование, должно стоять двоеточие, но два двоеточия подряд - это слишком, поэтому заменили на тире. Тире и двоеточие указывают на причинно-следственные связи, иногда они взаимозаменяемы, особенно в таких экспрессивных разговорных конструкциях, когда вторая часть носит присоединительный характер. Все три простых предложения можно было написать отдельно.

Он был против. Как так?! Под его крышей будут говорить о М.!

Comment: cпасибо! немного потерялась в пункте 4 и 5 :S что надо считать как БСП: выделенные моменты "разрешить мне видеться с малышом" и "снять с тебя мерки"? или комплетное предложение?

Comment: Правильно "потерялась", я поторопилась, не очень вникла, простите. Сейчас поправлю. Конечно же, это простые предложения с обособлением пояснительных членов, где тире ставится по аналогии с пунктуацией при  обособленных  несогласованных определениях и приложениях в конце предложения.

Answer (score 2):

1) Предложения 1, 2, 3 - бессоюзные сложные(БСП), в которых при отсутствии союзов (с определенным значением) отношения между простыми предложениями на письме обозначаются более сильными знаками препинания, чем запятая (двоеточием и тире).  Двоеточие относится к теме пояснения (предложение 1) и изъяснения (предложения 2,3), но оно в 2 и 3 заменяется тире (вопрос замены - это особая тема).

Здесь важно понять, что БСП - это как бы два самостоятельных  простых предложения, связанных определёнными отношениями. Иногда БСП довольно просто можно переделать в СПП, используя нужный союз,  а иногда это сделать сложнее, но в любом случае это самостоятельный тип предложения, и достраивать его до СПП необязательно.

2) Предложения 4 и 5 - простые осложненные (с обособлением), в них обособленный оборот на основе инфинитива поясняет значение местоимения "одно, об одном".

3) Он был против: как так – под его крышей будут говорить о М.

Это БСП со значением пояснения (против чего?), поэтому ставится двоеточие.

Выражение "как так (как это так)" напоминает междометное выражение со значением удивления или несогласия, поэтому оно должно обособляться. После него может ставиться авторский знак: запятая, тире, иногда двоеточие.

Примеры

Я знала, что среди зрителей многие недоумевали перед "Кармен": как это так, доверить такой ответственный спектакль молодой певице, без всяких званий?!

С места выходила какая-то безлепица: как это так― пришёл с покойным? [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

Comment: Arina: спасибо за помощь! особенное спасибо за абзац 2! поняла! =) 
вопрос: я правильно понимаю - если в предложении 1 стояла бы запятая, то это было бы изъяснительное придаточное? а двоеточие трансферирует его в БСП? так?
PD: Вы предложение 4 наме́ренно не упомянули или просто ошиблись в цифрах где-то?

Comment: Главный признак БСП - в нём нет союзов.  В предложении 1 тоже нет союза (КАК БЫ НЕ  не является союзом). Считается, что для связи простых предложений в БСП используется особая интонация, если это устная речь, а на письме ставятся тире или двоеточие. Эти знаки имеют способность  выражать определенную семантику, например пояснительную или изъяснительную. Так что для трансформации   БСП в СПП нужно убрать союз , а вместо запятой (при неоднородных отношениях) поставить нужный знак..Двоеточие (да и тире тоже) может выразить то  изъяснительное значение, которое в СПП имеет, например, союз ЧТО.

Comment: Arina: извините, пожалуйста, еще один вопрос: если предложение 1 бессоюзное, как надо интерпретировать "как"? разве это не союз?

Comment: согласна с Вами, "КАК БЫ НЕ не является союзом": "бы + сняла" делают вместе сослагательное наклонение; "не" - отрица́ние, потому что вместе нежелательное действие обозначают. но как надо тогда рассматривать "как"?

Comment: Как бы не - устойчивое сочетание "как бы+ не" в роли частицы для внесения в предложение чувства  опасения.

Comment: Сочетание КАК БЫ НЕ  упоминается в словаре, оно выступает в роли союза в СПП  вида " боюсь, как бы не опоздать". Но оно используется и в простых предложениях со значением опасения: Как бы не отстать от поезда!  По структуре оно похоже на риторический вопрос (отсюда местоимение КАК). Частица БЫ используется в предложениях со значением желания, например: "отдохнуть бы сейчас", а КАК БЫ НЕ  выражает нежелание. В приведенном предложении 1 "как бы она сейчас и на самом деле не сняла платье" является аналогом простого предложения, которое входит в БСП, поэтому КАК БЫ НЕ не является союзом, как в СПП